# TableLayout Tweak. Is it possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout with five columns and many rows with dynamic content.

We notice that each column takes the width of the maximum of all cells of that column.

I do not want horizontal scrolling but I want to detect when the total width has been exceeded so I can remove one of the columns.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call measure() on the TableLayout yourself and check the result with getMeasuredWidth/Height.

Comment: Say I measured each row... I need to know if its possible to remove a column without reproducing the whole table?

Comment: You can just collapse that column, TableLayout has an API for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding each row in a loop, then I guess you could do something like:

```
int longestRowWidth = 0;

for(i=0; i<6; i++) 
{

    // Add your row here

    // Get the width of your new row here
    int rowWidth = blablah


    // Check if it exceeds longestRowWidth
    if(rowWidth > longestRowWidth)
    {
        // Do your stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: how to do "blablah" is what this question is about I think :)

Comment: That´s a tough one, because Android hasn´t drawn the column yet, it has just been declared, therefore it has no width nor height.